# why do i get a none in my code at the end even whilst using return

Tags: python

I originally had this code and it would be fine for 1-99 but for the 100th it would say "None":

```
def f(n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            print("bacon and egg")
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            print("egg")
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            print("bacon")
        else:
            print("neither")

print(f(100))
```

So I tried to correct it and for this part of my code  it comes up with a "NameError: name 'neither' is not defined" as I tried to include return to no longer get the none:

```
def f(n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            return bacon and egg
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            return egg
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            return bacon
        else:
            return neither

print(f(100))
```

How would I fix this to no longer get the none?

Comment: Use your first code and just use: f(100) rather than print(f100)).  Printing is going on inside the f code.

Comment: @darryig I have done this but it still only does 1-99 how would I fix this to make it include 100?

Comment: @user12386893--range(1, n) will only include numbers from 1 to n-1.  If you want numbers from 1 to n, you should range(1, n+1).  Then f(100) will be from 1 to 100.

Comment: @darryig Thank you! I just remembered about this!

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on your 2nd example, it seems like the `NameError` is due to the fact `neither` isn't actually a populated variable, in which case, you could wrap it up as a string and return it :)

**Example**

```
def f(n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            return 'bacon and egg'
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            return 'egg'
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            return 'bacon'
        else:
            return 'neither'

print(f(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `print(f(100))` with `f(100)` to remove **None**.

```
def f(n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            print("bacon and egg")
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            print("egg")
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            print("bacon")
        else:
            print("neither")

f(100)
```